# Outlook API to get meeting details in c#

Tags: c#, outlook

I am trying to create an API for outlook using c# windows app. For that , to get all the AppointmentItem I am using the below code and it is working.

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application oApp = null;
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.NameSpace mapiNamespace = null;
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MAPIFolder CalendarFolder = null;
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MAPIFolder Inbox = null;
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Items outlookCalendarItems = null;

            oApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application();
            mapiNamespace = oApp.GetNamespace("MAPI"); ;
            mapiNamespace.Logon("", "",true, true);
            CalendarFolder = mapiNamespace.GetDefaultFolder(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderCalendar);
            CalendarFolder = oApp.Session.GetDefaultFolder(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderCalendar);
            DateTime startTime = DateTime.Now;
            DateTime endTime = startTime.AddDays(5);
            //string filter = "[Start] >= '"  + startTime.ToString("g")  + "' AND [End] <= '" + endTime.ToString("g") + "'";
            outlookCalendarItems = CalendarFolder.Items;
           // outlookCalendarItems.Restrict(filter);
           // outlookCalendarItems.Sort("Start");
            outlookCalendarItems.IncludeRecurrences = true;

            int i = 0;
            foreach (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.AppointmentItem item in outlookCalendarItems)
            {

                dataGridCalander.Rows.Add();
                dataGridCalander.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value = i + 1;

                if (item.Subject != null)
                {
                    dataGridCalander.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value = item.Subject;
                } 
}
```

Similar way , I want get the available meeting rooms created in outlook and status of that particular meeting rooms (available or not) . Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have noticed the following line of code:

```
 foreach (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.AppointmentItem item in outlookCalendarItems)
```

Don't iterate over all Outlook items in the loop. Use the Find/FindNext or Restrict methods to find the required subset.

Or use the [GetTable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff860692(v=office.15).aspx) method of the Folder class which obtains a Table object that contains items filtered by Filter. If Filter is a blank string or the Filter parameter is omitted, GetTable returns a Table with rows representing all the items in the Folder. If Filter is a blank string or the Filter parameter is omitted and TableContents is olHiddenItems, GetTable returns a Table with rows representing all the hidden items in the Folder.

```
Sub DemoTable()  
  'Declarations  
  Dim Filter As String  
  Dim oRow As Outlook.Row  
  Dim oTable As Outlook.Table  
  Dim oFolder As Outlook.Folder  

  'Get a Folder object for the Inbox  
  Set oFolder = Application.Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)  

  'Define Filter to obtain items last modified after May 1, 2005  
   Filter = "[LastModificationTime] > '5/1/2005'"  
  'Restrict with Filter  
   Set oTable = oFolder.GetTable(Filter)  

  'Enumerate the table using test for EndOfTable  
   Do Until (oTable.EndOfTable)  
     Set oRow = oTable.GetNextRow()  
     Debug.Print (oRow("Subject"))  
     Debug.Print (oRow("LastModificationTime"))  
   Loop  
 End Sub
```

The Outlook object model doesn't provide any method or property for rooms. You can use the [OpenSharedFolder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff867648(v=office.15).aspx) method of the Namespace class to open a shared calendar for a room.

Consider using EWS instead. See [EWS Managed API, EWS, and web services in Exchange](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dd877012%28v=exchg.150%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) for more information.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is it possible to get the resource available ?